# Chrome Devtools Memory Profiles Objects Count column removed?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When I in chrome 61.0.3149.0，Memory Profiles have Objects Count column.
[image]

But when I in chrome 72.0.3626.109, I have not find the Objects Count column.

[image]

Maybe the Objects Count had been removed in version x, but I hadn't found any docs.

Comment: The counts are displayed right after the name. It was changed in Chrome 70 via https://crrev.com/c/1109438. AFAICT it makes sorting by count impossible but I don't know if that's important so if you can provide a compelling evidence that it is, consider opening a bug report on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, now I know the counts position.